# Is supervised machine learning by definition predictive?

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to organize a cheat sheet of sorts for data science, and I am working with the basic distinction between description, inference, and prediction. As examples of the first I see unsupervised methods described, and for the last I see supervised methods. So my question is simply, do these two sets of categories align? Is unsupervised to supervised as description is to prediction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A description as any statistic drawn from your sample data, say the sample mean, quantiles, etc.. Inference is a conclusion drawn from your sample data about the population, e.g., rejecting or accepting some hypothesis or stating that a model is suitable or not for describing your data. Prediction is simply a guess about future observations, which hopefully uses your data and some function/model of the data in a way to formulate that guess.

Both unsupervised and supervised learning methods aim to learn a function of the data that predicts another variable (typically called y) so both are drawing an inference (i.e., a model is well suited to describe your data, see the first sentence [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning)). However, these two methods differ in what data is available. In supervised learning you are able to use an observed sample of y for training your model and in unsupervised learning, y is unobserved.

Hope that helps!

Comment: OK, it sounds like both types of learning methods can be for prediction, since both "aim to learn a function ... that predicts ...." I suppose then that it is more accurate for me to say that some unsupervised methods cab be used for description, such as simple clustering or principle component analysis. These don't predict, they just describe the structure of a distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Peter Flach has a nice small matrix that describes what you are looking for in his book, [Machine Learning, the art and science of algorithms that make sense of data](https://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~flach/mlbook/). I'll reproduce it below::

```
                      |     Predictive Model          |   Descriptive Model
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Supervised learning   | Classification, Regression    |  Subgroup discovery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unsupervised learning | Predictive clustering         |  Descriptive clustering,
                      |                               |  Association rule mining
```

Comment: Excellent -- that is just what I was looking for. And thanks for the reference too.

Comment: @ontoligent Classification can be descriptive, too. In this sue case, you only have to tag a (relatively small) sample of your overall data and through inference label all of them. Automated tags on images would be an example, where feeding 1000 cat/non-cat pictures into a SL algorithm helps describe an overall set of millions of pictures.

Comment: @Neuneck you're completely right, this table is really incomplete and is only meant to provide a very broad picture. There are loads of other models (e.g. label propagation, taxonomy learning, metric learning etc.) which don't really fall in any of these categories.